# ViewController infinite loop after modifying Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a Navigation / ViewController hierarchy problem ever since implementing a library for side-shelf navigation (https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/AMSlideMenu). The implementation of this library works fine with demo ViewControllers (as can be seen on the linked Github page), but when I adjusted it to include the actual ViewControllers I had been working with previously (which themselves also had worked fine on their own), my navigation flow breaks down.

My app's ViewControllers are currently structured as follows:

- Navigation controller
- Login ViewController
- Main ViewController (where the drawer-nav library kicks off)

  - SlideMenuLeftTableView

    - Navigation Controller

      - ItemsTable ViewController
      - AddPhoto ViewController
      - AddItemDetails ViewController
    - Navigation Controller

      - Demo ViewController

Before implementing the shelf-navigation library, my storyboard consisted only of the following ViewControllers, and I was not encountering issues:

- Navigation Controller
- Login ViewController
- ItemsTable ViewController
- AddPhoto ViewController
- AddItemDetails ViewController

At the ItemsTable ViewController, as is expected, users see a TableView of Items they have added. As it was before (we're still good at this point), users click an "Add" button from the ItemsTable ViewController and go to the AddPhoto ViewController. User chooses the photo and is taken to AddItemDetails ViewController, where user adds a title for this photo.

*Here, though, is where it breaks down.*

The Item upload itself actually works, as the newly added Item shows up in my Parse data browser, as well as in the ItemsTableView after I close and relaunch the app. But when I click the button to add the Item within the AddItemDetails ViewController, instead of taking me back to TableViewController with the list of items updated to include the new Item, I am taken back to the UICameraPicker, where I am caught in a loop of adding photos for items, but never getting back to the TableViewController to look at them. When I click the cancel button on the UICameraPicker I get this warning message:

```
2014-05-31 23:04:26.312 GetGa[6872:90b] Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UINavigationController: 0x10b637f60>.
```

**AddPhoto ViewController** (where I'm getting stuck in the loop)

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"givePhotoToGiveDetailsSegue"]){
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[JFGiveItemDetailsVC class]]){
            JFGiveItemDetailsVC *targetVC = segue.destinationViewController;
            targetVC.giveItemImage = self.giveItemImage;
        }
    }
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]){
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if(!image) image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.giveItemImage = image;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"givePhotoToGiveDetailsSegue" sender:self];

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

**AddItemDetails ViewController** (which should send me back to the ItemsTable ViewController)

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *nameForGiveItem = self.giveItemTitleTextField.text;
    NSData *giveItemImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.giveItemImage);
    PFFile *giveItemImageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:nameForGiveItem data:giveItemImageData];
    PFObject *giveItemPhoto = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"giveItemPhoto"];
    giveItemPhoto[@"imageOwner"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    giveItemPhoto[@"imageName"] = nameForGiveItem;
    giveItemPhoto[@"imageFile"] = giveItemImageFile;

    [giveItemPhoto saveInBackground];

    PFObject *giveItem = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"giveItem"];
    giveItem[@"giveItemTitle"] = self.giveItemTitleTextField.text;
    giveItem[@"giver"] = [PFUser currentUser];
    [giveItem setObject:giveItemPhoto forKey:@"giveItemPhoto"];
    [giveItem saveInBackground];

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at the same issue. Here is what I did, in your `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` function write this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
MJLoginViewController *loginController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

If you are using iOS 7 then `storyboardWithName:@"Main"` would be the same for you.
MJLoginViewController is a class for a view controller in my Main.Storyborad and `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"` here you should write your storyboard ID name. If you have not given one go on assign one.

Run and it will work.